# Integral of $x^{-x}$ from $0$ to infinity $=$ $2$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Numerical evidence from Wolfram seems to indicate this. Is this just a numerical coincidence, and if not, can someone explain it?

Another interesting, if unrelated numerical coincidence: Wolfram's approximation of the integral of $x^{-x}$ from $0$ to $1$ is the same as its value for the sum of $n^{-n}$ from $1$ to infinity.

Comment: The second observation is called [The Shophomore's Dream](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Comment: Way cool.  This has got to be a known result, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Hmmm...  I've come up with good summations for the indefinite integral of $x^x$ and $x^{x^x}} $ (my proofs are detailed on my first question here on SE if you want proofs)...  I'm pretty sure the same logic could be used here,  and then limits could be taken

Comment: The numerical integration of Mathematica returns $1.9954559575001380005$. Not 2, that is.

Comment: I think I can solve this if you allow me to use a Puiseux series

Comment: I'll allow you to use whatever rigorous method you like. Although if that's what Mathematica says it may not be true, unfortunately.

Comment: A computation of this integral was carried out by G N Watson, Theorems stated by Ramanujan. VIII: Theorems on divergent series, J London Math Soc 4 (1929) 82-86. It has been carried out to over 100 decimals at https://oeis.org/A229191.

Comment: https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**
The Puiseux series for $x^x$ is
$$x^{-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^n \log^n(x)}{n!}$$
If we take the antiderivative we get
$$\int \bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^n \log^n(x)}{n!}\bigg)dx$$ 
$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int (-1)^n\frac{x^n \log^n(x)}{n!}dx$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int x^n \log^n(x)dx\bigg)$$
We then note that
$$\int x^n \log^n(x)dx = \frac{\Gamma(n+1,-(n+1)\log(x))(-n-1)^{-n} }{(n+1)}$$
Substituting, we get that
$$\int x^{-x} dx =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg((-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n+1,-(n+1)\log(x))(-n-1)^{-n} }{\Gamma(n+2)}\bigg)$$
Note that if we let $x=1$ we can check this series with the Sophmore's Dream (also note that the integral is $0$ when evaluated at $0$, so all we need is the upper limit)
$$\int x^{-x} dx =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg((-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n+1,-(n+1)\log(x))(-n-1)^{-n} }{\Gamma(n+2)}\bigg)$$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg((-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n+1,0)(-n-1)^{-n} }{\Gamma(n+2)}\bigg)$$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg((-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n+1)(-n-1)^{-n} }{\Gamma(n+2)}\bigg) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^{-(n+1)}$$
We now let $u=n+1$ and get
$$= \sum_{u=1}^{\infty}(u)^{-u} = \text{Sophmore's Dream}$$
Now that we are convinced let's head back and take the limit. We desire to find
$$\lim_{r \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg((-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n+1,-(n+1)\log(r))(-n-1)^{-n} }{\Gamma(n+2)}\bigg)$$
Honestly, I can't figure out how this limit could converge, but it must if the integral is already known. Perhaps someone more versed in limits of this type could lend a hand!

**Update**
I fear that I may have naively stepped outside of the interval of convergence for the series, so this approach is unlikely to work as is